# What Cloud Run CPU and Memory limits do App Engine Standard instance classes map to?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-run

I am migrating from App Engine to Cloud Run. App Engine Standard instance classes are defined [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes). I would like to know to what CPU and Memory configuration they map to in Cloud Run.

Comment: Yes, this will be added to the documentation too.

Answer (score 3):

**tl,dr**: An `F4` App Engine instance is roughly equivalent to `1` CPU and `1Gi` Memory in Cloud Run.

**Memory**: [This table](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes) shows exactly how much memory each instance class gets:

**CPU**: Cloud Run doesn't give details about the CPU frequency (it might change over time), it only guarantees a CPU quantity. `F1` and `F2` App Engine instances map to `0.25` and `0.5` CPU in Cloud Run, [selecting a CPU < 1 in Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu)  comes with limitations on other settings (e.g. concurrency). So the recommendation is to pick `1` CPU for these instance classes too.

| App Engine instance class | Cloud Run CPU equivalent | Cloud Run Memory equivalent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F1 | 0.25 | 256 MiB |
| F2 | 0.5 | 512 MiB |
| F4 | 1 | 1 GiB |
| F4 _1G | 1 | 2 GiB |